# How to combine two IMPORTXML values in one cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

All I need to do is combine two import values into one cell (to create a title).

I've tried:

```
=textjoin(IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php", "inventory/listing/make"),IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php", "inventory/listing/model"))
```

Which doesn't work at all.

I've also tried:

```
={IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php", "inventory/listing/make");IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php", "inventory/listing/model")}
```

Which does pull both, but it lists out all of the makes into their own cells first, then the models into their own cells after.

How can I combine these two imports into single cells? Surely this is possible, but I cannot even find other people attempting to do this for some reason. Do I need to use Apps Script?

**The result I want:**

```
|----------------|
| "MAKE1 MODEL1" |
|----------------|
| "MAKE2 MODEL2" |
|----------------|
| "MAKE3 MODEL3" |
|----------------|
```

**The current result:**

```
|----------|
| "MAKE1"  |
|----------|
| "MAKE2"  |
|----------|
| "MAKE3"  |
|----------|
| "MODEL1" |
|----------|
| "MODEL2" |
|----------|
| "MODEL3" |
|----------|
```

Comment: @BlindSpots I also edited the post to show example of my output, and what I need instead.

Answer (score 1):

### PART 1:    Wrong Array Separator

<sup><sub>***** *There's a formula further down the page in* **Part 2: CONCATENATE, MAP, & LAMBDA** *that achieves your objective*</sub></sup>
You are getting the array result based on the array separator you chose. Once you switch from a vertical separator to a horizontal separator, you will return the data in your preferred order.

| Countries | { Horizontal, Array, Separator } | { Vertical; Array; Separator } |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Non-EU** | **<kbd>,</kbd>** comma | **<kbd>;</kbd>** semi-colon |
| **EU** | **<kbd>\</kbd>** back-slash | **<kbd>;</kbd>** semi-colon |

###### Your Array Formula

```
={ IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php",  
             "inventory/listing/make");
   IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php", 
             "inventory/listing/model") }
```

###### Your Formula, Your Sample Data

```
={ {"MAKE1"; "MAKE2"; "MAKE3"};
   {"MODEL1"; "MODEL2"; "MODEL3"} }

=  { "MAKE1";
     "MAKE2";
     "MAKE3";
     "MODEL1";
     "MODEL2";
     "MODEL3" }
```

###### After Switching to a Horizontal Array Separator.

```
={ {"MAKE1"; "MAKE2"; "MAKE3"},
   {"MODEL1"; "MODEL2"; "MODEL3"} }

=  { "MAKE1", "MODEL1";
     "MAKE2", "MODEL2";
     "MAKE3", "MODEL3" }
```

### PART 2:    CONCATENATE,  MAP,  &  LAMBDA

###### Formula Syntax

```
=MAP( array1, 
      array2, 
      LAMBDA(name1, name2, name1 &" "& name2) )
```

###### With your Sample Data

```
=MAP( {"MAKE1"; "MAKE2"; "MAKE3"},
      {"MODEL1"; "MODEL2"; "MODEL3"}, 
      LAMBDA(mk, mdl, mk &" "& mdl) )

=     { "MAKE1 MODEL1";
        "MAKE2 MODEL2";
        "MAKE3 MODEL3" }
```

###### Your IMPORTXML Functions

```
=MAP( IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php",
                "inventory/listing/make"), 
      IMPORTXML("https://example.com/modules/feed/vehicle.php",
                "inventory/listing/model"),
      LAMBDA(mk, mdl, mk &" "& mdl) )
```